# How to go from Insert mode to Normal mode in Vim running in IntelliJ IDEA terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim

How to switch from Insert mode to Normal mode in Vim editor running in terminal window of Idea?

When Vim is running outside Idea, <kbd>Esc</kbd> key can be used. However default Idea keymap uses <kbd>Esc</kbd> for action "Focus editor". So when pressed, instead on switching mode in Vim, focus is moved from terminal window to Idea's editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Vim shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to exit Insert mode and abort current command. Vim also uses shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to exit Insert mode. In some Idea keymaps this shortcut is mapped as well though.

Or

alternatively remap allow shortcuts overriding for Terminal in Idea:
Menu > Settings > Tools > Terminal > Override IDE shortcuts

and adjust mapping for action "Switch Focus To Editor":
Menu > Settings > Keymap > Plugins > Terminal > Switch Focus To Editor

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the IdeaVim icon at the bottom right of your screen > Open ~/.ideavimrc

Then write in

`imap your key combination <Esc>`

Ex: `imap jk <Esc>`, and pressing <kbd>j</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> will return you to Normal mode from Insert mode.

Comment: IIUIC IdeaVim here references the [vim engine for JetBrains IDEs](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim). The question though asks about vanilla Vim running in terminal window of vanilla Idea.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the nuance.